# How can I change the color of a custom shape in photoshop with multiple colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, shapes

I am working with custom shapes in photoshop and when I click bucket fill, it fills the entire image with one color.  Are there ways to make the image multiple colors?  For instance, if I had a butterfly, would like the body of the butterfly one color and the wings a different color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

based on ur question, it looks like u are trying to fill the shape with different colour on different part on the same canvas. As shape came in a from of 1 space area, so bucket tool can only fill everything inside it. however, theres a lot of different tools can be use to manually refill the color by using selection method. You can use pen tools or lasso tools to do ur selection.

Answer (score 0):

Methods:
1. Use the 'Select area' tools, the fill the selected area only
2. Draw lines between the areas, then fill each the same way as before.
...